# MYSQL 8.0.17 CHECK not working even though it has been implemented

Tags: mysql, constraints

The `CHECK` constraints have been completely implemented since 8.0.16 according to the manual of MYSQL. But when I tried creating a table using that, it is not showing any error when the `CHECK` fails. What is going wrong?
Here is my code to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (ENUM INT(4) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
FNAME varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
MNAME varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL, 
LNAME varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
BIRTHDATE date NOT NULL, 
GENDER char(1) CHECK(GENDER IN ('M', 'F')), 
SSN varchar(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
JOB_TITLE varchar(20) CHECK(JOB_TITLE IN ('Lecturer', 'Professor', 'Asst. Professor', 'Sr. Lecturer')),  
SALARY numeric(10, 2) NOT NULL, 
HIREDATE date NOT NULL, 
TAX numeric(8, 2) NOT NULL, 
DEPARTMENT varchar(20) CHECK(DEPARTMENT IN ('Biotechnology', 'Computer Science', 'Nano Technology', 'Information Technology')), 
PRIMARY KEY(ENUM));
```

Here, `JOB_TITLE` has the check to be in the list and same with `DEPARTMENT`. But this query:

```
INSERT INTO Employee (FNAME, MNAME, LNAME, BIRTHDATE, GENDER, SSN, JOB_TITLE,  SALARY, HIREDATE, TAX, DEPARTMENT ) VALUES 
 ('Sangeet', 'R', 'Sharma', date '1965-11-08', 'M', '11MH456633', 'Prof', 1200900, date '1990-12-16', 120090, 'Computer');
```

is being accepted without any error. why is this so?

Comment: Working as expected on my laptop, I get an "ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'Employee_chk_2' is violated."

Comment: Check your MySQL server version, upto the patch number (sub-version). Anyways, the way you are using `CHECK` constraint here, I would instead implement those requirements using `ENUM` data-type.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya when I use `mysql` on powershell, it is connecting to an older version of server even though I have 8.0.17 version. I even deleted other mysql paths from system variable, still the same is happening. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
INSERT INTO Employee (FNAME, 
                      MNAME, 
                      LNAME, 
                      BIRTHDATE, 
                      GENDER, 
                      SSN, 
                      JOB_TITLE,  
                      SALARY, 
                      HIREDATE, 
                      TAX, 
                      DEPARTMENT 
                      ) 
VALUES              ('Sangeet',
                     'R', 
                     'Sharma', 
                     date '1965-11-08',
                     'M', 
                     '11MH456633', 
                     'Professor',
                     1200900,
                     date '1990-12-16', 
                     120090, 
                     'Computer Science'
                     );
```

employee_chk_2 is violated in your version of the query as you are trying to use 'Prof.' instead of 'Professor'. And employee_chk_3 is violated because you are trying to insert 'Computer' instead of 'Computer Science'.  The check constraints are working as you established them.